# Is it possible to change the type of the input tensor in the coreml model from multiarray to image?

Tags: image, tensorflow, coreml

I have a coreml model with those parameters and I want to change the type of the input tensor from Multiarray with shapes (112,112,3) to RGB image(112,112)

```
Core ML input(s):
[name: "input_to_float__0"
type {
multiArrayType {
shape: 3
shape: 112
shape: 112
dataType: DOUBLE
}
}
]
Core ML output(s):
[name: "logits__BiasAdd__0"
type {
multiArrayType {
shape: 80
dataType: DOUBLE
} 
}
]
```

[image]

Is it possible to do that?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

It's easiest to specify this when you convert the model to Core ML (using `image_input_names`).

But you can also fix this using a bit of Python:

```
import coremltools
import coremltools.proto.FeatureTypes_pb2 as ft
spec = coremltools.utils.load_spec("YourModel.mlmodel")
input = spec.description.input[0]
input.type.imageType.colorSpace = ft.ImageFeatureType.RGB
input.type.imageType.height = 112
input.type.imageType.width = 112
coremltools.utils.save_spec(spec, "YourNewModel.mlmodel")
```

Comment: I solved my problem , I found a solution on the github and it works fine thanks for your answer